# Stopping a servo while loop with

Tags: c++, arduino, adafruit

I am building a project that involves a servo and an adifruit circuit playground express. My goal is to have the board go through a light sequence, have the servo turn 15 degrees, turn back 15 degrees and then repeat after a 10 second delay while being initiated by the A button. This will go until the B button is pressed essentially breaking the while loop that was entered with the press of the A button.
I've thought of having the while loop check for if a value is still considered 'true' each time it loops which led me to believe I should try a 'switch-case' idea but I was not sure what to put in the switch().
Here is some of what I have. It's only 2 IF statements but the 'buttonPressedA' if statement runs infinitely without the possibility of breaking out of it. Help with this would be really appreciated.

```
     // and here, we, go. (just like the joker says it) 
#include <Adafruit_CircuitPlayground.h>
#include <Servo.h> // servo library 
#define NEOPIX_PIN A2
#define NUM_PIXELS 5 


Servo nohands; // creating an object so reference the servo library, no hands. get it. cuz you're not using hands... alright that's it. 

    int pos = 15; // varible to store the servo position. ALSO HAS THE START POSITION FOR THE SERVO 

bool leftButtonPressedA;
bool rightButtonPressedB;
uint8_t pixeln = 0;

Adafruit_CPlay_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_CPlay_NeoPixel(NUM_PIXELS, NEOPIX_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
 
  Serial.println("Don't touch the wheel. I've got it from here!");
  Serial.begin(9600);
  CircuitPlayground.begin();
  strip.begin();
  nohands.attach(A7); //we are looking for pin A7
  nohands.write(0); // setting the pos to 0 
}





void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  leftButtonPressedA = CircuitPlayground.leftButton();
  rightButtonPressedB = CircuitPlayground.rightButton();
  CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
  //*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if (leftButtonPressedA) {
    while(1) {     // while loop to run infinite 
      delay(100); // will delay the timing of the loop by intervals of 10 seconds 
  Serial.println("GO");
  strip.clear();
  strip.show();
  delay(1000);  // will delay 1 second before initiallizing the light sequence 
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,40,40,0);
  delay(200); // will delay the progression by x ms (*10^-3sec) before moving onto the next one. 
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,40,40,0);     
  delay(200);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,40,40,0);
  delay(200);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,40,40,0);     
  delay(200);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,40,40,0);     
  delay(100);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,40,40,0);     //lights 
  delay(100);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,40,40,0);     
  delay(100);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,40,40,0);     
  delay(100);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,40,40,0);     
  delay(100);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,40,40,0);     
  delay(100);
  strip.show(); 
  strip.clear();
  
  strip.show();
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,0,0,0);     //lights 
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
strip.show();
strip.clear();

strip.show();
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,0,200,0);     //lights 
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
    CircuitPlayground.playTone(500 + pixeln * 500, 100);
      CircuitPlayground.playTone(750 + pixeln * 750, 100);
        CircuitPlayground.playTone(1000 + pixeln * 200, 100); 
   /*delay(2000); // will shwo the lights all for a total of 5 seconds before it goes back to reloading */
   strip.clear(); 
   //*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //beginning of servo for loop 
   
   for (pos = 0;  pos <=15; pos += 3) {// set to 15 degrees
    //pos+= is stepping in intervals of 1 degree 
   nohands.write(pos); 
   delay(150); 
   }
   for (pos = 15; pos >= 0 ; pos -= 3){           // set to 15 degrees 
    nohands.write(pos);                                 //adding while loop will have the entire think loop go for ever. 
    delay(150);
   }
  
   
   
   // end of GO
    }
  }
  
 
 

//*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if (rightButtonPressedB) {
Serial.println("STOP");
strip.show();
  delay(100);  // will delay 1 second before initiallizing the light sequence 
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,150,0,0);
  delay(50); // will delay the progression by x ms (*10^-3sec) before moving onto the next one. 
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,150,0,0);
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,150,0,0);     //lights 
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  strip.show(); 
  strip.clear();

 strip.show();
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,0,0,0);     //lights 
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  
strip.clear();     
strip.show();
CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,255,0,0);
  delay(50); // will delay the progression by x ms (*10^-3sec) before moving onto the next one. 
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,255,0,0);
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,255,0,0);     //lights 
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);

  CircuitPlayground.playTone(1000 + pixeln * 200, 100);
      CircuitPlayground.playTone(750 + pixeln * 750, 100);
        CircuitPlayground.playTone(500 + pixeln * 500, 100);
  delay(2000); // will show the lights all for a total of 5 seconds before it goes back to reloading 
//*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
  } // end of STOP
  
  } `// and here, we, go. (just like the joker says it) 
#include <Adafruit_CircuitPlayground.h>
#include <Servo.h> // servo library 
#define NEOPIX_PIN A2
#define NUM_PIXELS 5 


Servo nohands; // creating an object so reference the servo library, no hands. get it. cuz you're not using hands... alright that's it. 

    int pos = 15; // varible to store the servo position. ALSO HAS THE START POSITION FOR THE SERVO 

bool leftButtonPressedA;
bool rightButtonPressedB;
uint8_t pixeln = 0;

Adafruit_CPlay_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_CPlay_NeoPixel(NUM_PIXELS, NEOPIX_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
 
  Serial.println("Don't touch the wheel. I've got it from here!");
  Serial.begin(9600);
  CircuitPlayground.begin();
  strip.begin();
  nohands.attach(A7); //we are looking for pin A7
  nohands.write(0); // setting the pos to 0 
}





void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  leftButtonPressedA = CircuitPlayground.leftButton();
  rightButtonPressedB = CircuitPlayground.rightButton();
  CircuitPlayground.clearPixels();
  //*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if (leftButtonPressedA) {
    while(1) {     // while loop to run infinite 
      delay(100); // will delay the timing of the loop by intervals of 10 seconds 
  Serial.println("GO");
  strip.clear();
  strip.show();
  delay(1000);  // will delay 1 second before initiallizing the light sequence 
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,40,40,0);
  delay(200); // will delay the progression by x ms (*10^-3sec) before moving onto the next one. 
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,40,40,0);     
  delay(200);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,40,40,0);
  delay(200);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,40,40,0);     
  delay(200);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,40,40,0);     
  delay(100);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,40,40,0);     //lights 
  delay(100);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,40,40,0);     
  delay(100);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,40,40,0);     
  delay(100);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,40,40,0);     
  delay(100);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,40,40,0);     
  delay(100);
  strip.show(); 
  strip.clear();
  
  strip.show();
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,0,0,0);     //lights 
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
strip.show();
strip.clear();

strip.show();
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,0,200,0);     //lights 
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,0,200,0);     
  delay(0.5);
    CircuitPlayground.playTone(500 + pixeln * 500, 100);
      CircuitPlayground.playTone(750 + pixeln * 750, 100);
        CircuitPlayground.playTone(1000 + pixeln * 200, 100); 
   /*delay(2000); // will shwo the lights all for a total of 5 seconds before it goes back to reloading */
   strip.clear(); 
   //*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //beginning of servo for loop 
   
   for (pos = 0;  pos <=15; pos += 3) {// set to 15 degrees
    //pos+= is stepping in intervals of 1 degree 
   nohands.write(pos); 
   delay(150); 
   }
   for (pos = 15; pos >= 0 ; pos -= 3){           // set to 15 degrees 
    nohands.write(pos);                                 //adding while loop will have the entire think loop go for ever. 
    delay(150);
   }
  
   
   
   // end of GO
    }
  }
  
 
 

//*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if (rightButtonPressedB) {
Serial.println("STOP");
strip.show();
  delay(100);  // will delay 1 second before initiallizing the light sequence 
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,150,0,0);
  delay(50); // will delay the progression by x ms (*10^-3sec) before moving onto the next one. 
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,150,0,0);
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,150,0,0);     //lights 
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,150,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  strip.show(); 
  strip.clear();

 strip.show();
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,0,0,0);     //lights 
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,0,0,0);     
  delay(25);
  
strip.clear();     
strip.show();
CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(9,255,0,0);
  delay(50); // will delay the progression by x ms (*10^-3sec) before moving onto the next one. 
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(8,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(7,255,0,0);
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(6,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(5,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(4,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(3,255,0,0);     //lights 
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(2,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(1,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);
  CircuitPlayground.setPixelColor(0,255,0,0);     
  delay(50);

  CircuitPlayground.playTone(1000 + pixeln * 200, 100);
      CircuitPlayground.playTone(750 + pixeln * 750, 100);
        CircuitPlayground.playTone(500 + pixeln * 500, 100);
  delay(2000); // will show the lights all for a total of 5 seconds before it goes back to reloading 
//*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
  } // end of STOP
  
  

}
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. What exactly does not work? 2. Is the display code necessary? If not, please remove it and provide a minimal example.

Comment: 1. What is not working is that I want to end the loop that is entered by starting the motor and I am not sure how to end it.

Comment: I would suggest that you use an interrupt for button B. In button B's interrupt function, set a variable, e.g. `abort = true;`. In your loop, query for `abort`. If abort is true, exit the loop with `break`. By using an interrupt, you can press B at any time during your loop and do not have to wait until the light show is over.

Answer (score 1):

attention to the fact that when you press **B** the microcontroller is executing one of the **delay** lines, therefore doesn't check the **if(rightButtonPressedB)** condition nor B button state.

Try this function instead of delay(x):

```
    void my_delay(int x):{
        int i=0;
            while(!rightButtonPressedB and i<x){
              rightButtonPressedB = CircuitPlayground.rightButton();
              delay(1);
              i++;
        }
    }
```